# Neovim does not recognize Python modules installed in a virtual environment

Tags: python, linux, pip, debian, neovim

I am using the AstroNvim configuration with pyright and pylint installed via Mason. Neovim doesn't recognize the imported modules installed via pip in a virtual environment, but it executes just fine.
I have the same problem whether I use Fedora or Debian.

I import installed modules in my Python virtual environment, it's raising an error but it executes fine.

Comment: wild guess is that your vim config points to the python executable that is not inside your venv.